# Why is it possible for an int and a float to operate together in Java?

Tags: java, floating-point, type-conversion, integer

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     float result = (int)Math.floor(1.5F);
        System.out.println(result);
```

so this is what I plugged into java
but what I'm wondering is...
shouldn't it be:
float result = (float)Math.floor(1.5F); ?

because the result is looking for a float but (int)Math.floor(1.5F) produces an int
or atleast thats what my noob brain is thinking :/

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of Widening Primitive Conversion in Java. See [the official Java spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html) for more information (scroll down to `5.1.2. Widening Primitive Conversion` and the related `5.1.3. Narrowing Primitive Conversion`).

Specifically in your case, you're seeing:

> A widening conversion of an int or a long value to float, or of a long
> value to double, may result in loss of precision - that is, the result
> may lose some of the least significant bits of the value. In this
> case, the resulting floating-point value will be a correctly rounded
> version of the integer value, using IEEE 754 round-to-nearest mode
> (§4.2.4).